# Creating a custom Section class for MonoTouch.Dialog?

Tags: iphone, ios, mono, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I'd like to create a class that is a custom Section, from MonoTouch.Dialog, that overrides certain methods and such.  Is there an API somewhere that I can find the methods to override or a good example of this being done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the [MT.Dialog source](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog) is hosted on Github